# Push notifications arrive after a long time on some devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

On Android, I have been experiencing long push delay in some devices (minutes, half an hour). Seems like the device is asleep (but not for WhatsApp). Even on Pre-Marshmallow devices.

**After a while they don't respond to push**.

I have created a simple app (copied [Google's Cloud Messaging client sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)).

Tried to send push via The Firebase Console, setting priority to HIGH and made sure it works.

- Experiment 1: After a while - tried to send. The device is not responding.
- Experiment 2: Tried to use Telegram and WhatsApp. Message passes immediately on both.
- Experiment 3: Tried the my test app again. Not working.
- Experiment 4: Tried to downgrade from FCM to GCM and all the way to C2DM. Same thing, not working.

Any ideas?

To make it clear:

- The token is okay. In most cases it works. It just falls asleep after a while.
- It's a Lollipop device so **no Power Saving exempts here or battery saving**.
- I use `priority:high` on the payload.
- It is no server issue because I use FCM composer and it's just the same.
- Waking the device does not necessarily fix it. It just begins to receive notifications minutes later and then all ok.
- Other apps such as WhatsApp work without problem whatsoever, always.
- I tried C2DM, GCM, FCM. I am using a printout on the C2DM receiver. They all behave the same.
- I log everything. Every event, broadcast I get. I don't get push when I should.

*Possible clue:* some of my customers are using VMWare AirWatch. anybody know about any issues related to AirWatch and Push?

Answer (score 1):

This is not *a complete answer* so I can't mark this question "Answered".

I found some alternative push mechanism called [Pushy](https://pushy.me/). It's mentioned quite a lot in Stack Overflow.

Pros:

- I have made tests on a phone where FCM and GCM failed. Pushy succeeded to deliver all my messages, always.
- It can work on devices with no Google Play Services enabled
- It is also a workaround for the `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` issue.
- They have a nice friendly console like in FCM, where you can send test messages.
- You get a feedback when the message was delivered to Android devices.
- Has topics like in FCM so you can send one message to a group.

Cons:

- Money. It costs. Not too much. Last time I checked it was 0.5Cent per month for each active user. It may be a lot but my app is an emergency app so availability is a must in my case.
- Does not have retries like FCM, as far as I understood. I may be wrong but it does not handle many things that FCM does. It may not do exponential back-off retries or Notification Messages A-la-Apple. I personally hate FCM behaviour on that so I am fine with this.